# how deploy uwp app with settings

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

Normally I ship my applications with a predefined configuration which is located in the app.config. So I can publish for customer A other predefined settings then for customer B

How can I achieve this in uwp?

Comment: Are you deploying the app via side-loading?

Comment: Yes, thats the current plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As UWP apps are intended to be deployed via the Store, there's no need for an `app.config` file any longer. If you still want to produce a similar behavior, you'll have to work using compiler directives.

The easiest way would be to create a file similiar to the well-known `app.config`:

```xml
<Config>
    <!-- key-value pairs go here -->
</Config>
```

Create a config file for every customer you have...

- `Assets`

  - `CustomerA.config`
  - `CustomerB.config`
  - `CustomerC.config`

...and load it via a compiler directive:

```cs
public Config GetConfig()
{
    var configFileName = GetConfigName();
    // Load config...
}

private string GetConfigName()
{
#if CUSTA
    return "CustomerA.config";
#endif
#if CUSTB
    return "CustomerB.config";
#endif
#if CUSTC
    return "CustomerC.config";
#endif
    throw new NotSupportedException(
        "Assembly was compiled for a customer which config doesn't exist.");
}
```

**Note:** If the amount of different config files might increase to an unknown number, you'd rather implement a web service identifying the customer and providing the config.

***EDIT:*** Using a single configuration file in your app would also be possible (that would prevent the compiler directives), and therefore modify the XML via XSLT in different build configurations.
The principle stays the same, but you got the annoying part out of your code into XSLT.

Comment: When placing the CustomerA.config, CustomerB.config ... into the folder Assets will they be deployed to every customer? Since every customer got his own web service uri and I want to store them into the .config file, it would be bad that customerA can see the webservice config of customerB.

Comment: @Briefkasten Then you'd rather use what I wrote in my edit. Use a single `XML` file that will be modified via a XSLT for each customer. Due to this, each customer will receive their own XML and won't be able to see those of others.

Answer (score 1):

Use this settings class https://github.com/joseangelmt/ObservableSettings.
With it you don't need to create a xml file and you can set predefined values via attribute decoration of your properties, and also it's observable.